# Run exe without ms-dos windows

Tags: c++, windows-7, cygwin, netbeans-8

I'm compiling a simple script that displays a window.

I use Netbeans 8, compile with Cygwin and program in C++. Everything works fine but when I double click the exe file, an MS-DOS windows opens too.

How can I avoid that?

**EDIT**
If I run the exe from the terminal it correctly opens only the application..

Answer (score 0):

I think you must built a console application.
Check your project setting, the problem is independent of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Select the proper sub system in linker configuration. Right-click the project -> Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem, Select "Windows".